# Angular Cli Include External Scripts as if on window

Tags: angular

The Angular cli documentation states:

> Some javascript libraries need to be added to the global scope, and
>   loaded as if they were in a script tag. We can do this using the
>   apps[0].scripts and apps[0].styles properties of angular-cli.json.

But I have tried to include a third party script which should add a variable `Tour` to the window:

```
"scripts": [ 
    // jQuery, bootstrap, etc...
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-tour/build/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js"
```

When accessing `Tour` from the window, I get that `Tour` is `undefined`.

If I include the exact same script with a script tag, `Tour` is on the window just fine. I do not care about typings in this instance (there are none for this library). Am I missing a step?

The workaround I am using is to put the static JS files in the assets folder - the issue there is I have to put all of their dependencies in the assets folder as well, but I want them bundled if possible.

Edit: The way I am accessing Tour is through the developer console - it should be on the window (and is when included statically). In TypeScript, I use `declare const Tour` which works when included statically as well.

Comment: Please add code of how you access `Tour` variable and where the error occurs.

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski Access Tour from the developer console, as it should be on the window. If it's in typescript i would do a `declare const Tour`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by calling `require` in index.ts for the files I needed after including them in `angular-cli.json`.

`angular-cli.json`:

```
  "scripts": [
    ...
    "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
    "../node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"
  ]
```

`index.ts`:

```
declare const require;
require('moment/moment.js');
require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');
export * from './environment';
export * from './app.component';
export * from './app.module';
```

If anyone knows a more appropriate way, let me know!